# I can use value preg_match only once

Tags: php, html, variables, preg-match

I have a preg_match command ;

```
<?php
    $content = "<span class='hotels'><div id='general_parcel_id'></div></span>";
    $wanted=preg_match ('/<span class=\'hotels\'>(.*?)<\/span>/', $content, $result);
    $resultant = $result[1];
?>
```

Note : `<div id='general_parcel_id'></div>` prints an id for each product on the page.

and finally I want to use this $resultant variable, for a database connection.

Ex.

```
$dbase = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from hotex WHERE parcel_id = '$resultant'"));
```

but this is not possible. Write the result as variable once. Only once

Thank you in advance ...

Comment: Please can you paste your whole script, or at least everything between the 1st and 2nd sections. PHP will not unset variables but you might have a scoping issue or be accidentally reassigning it yourself. Also, what is the output of `echo $resultant;`

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML... Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @M1ke This is the entire script. There's nothing between the two. Output of echo $ resultant = variable of the product on the page (Ex: 162, 163, 164, etc.) different on each page.

Comment: @M1ke 'echo $resultant' gives me results. But, can not be assigned to a variable in the database connection.

Comment: @Pete does not preg_match_all

Comment: Add to your original post: output of `echo $resultant;` and then output of `echo "select * from hotex WHERE parcel_id = '$resultant'";`

Comment: Essentially there is no reason that a variable will be set in one line and not in the next. So either the variable is set and something else is wrong, or there's code in between those lines.

Comment: Dear @M1ke this is a variable. For example, a page : `echo $resultant;` = **162**  `echo "select * from hotex WHERE parcel_id = '$resultant'";` = **162 = 162**  `echo <div id='general_parcel_id'></div>`  = **162** . Another to another page. Ex **163**

Comment: @M1ke So my problem Assign this div value ( `<div id='general_parcel_id'></div>` ) to $resultant  variable.   Like this `<$resultant = <div id='general_parcel_id'></div>`

Comment: Those aren't the outputs of the `echo` commands. I'm asking to help debug your code because your problem isn't clear; add those `echo` lines into your code and add the output to your question.